# Neo4j: How to return deep node data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Dataset

```
CREATE
  (u1:User {number: 1}), (u2:User {number: 2}),
  (r1:Room {name: 'r1'}), (r2:Room {name: 'r2'}),
  (d1:UnavailableDate {date: '1/1/2016'}), (d2:UnavailableDate {date: '1/2/2016'}),
  (i1:Image {url: 'http://..'}), (i2:Image {url: 'http://..'}),(i3:Image {url: 'http://..'}),
  (pA:Place {name: 'P'}),
  (u1)<-[:house_mate]-(pA)-[:owner_of]->(u2),
  (pA)<-[:place]-(r1),
  (pA)<-[:place]-(r2),
  (r1)<-[:room]-(d1),
  (r1)<-[:room]-(d2),
  (r2)<-[:room]-(i1),
  (r2)<-[:room]-(i2),
  (r1)<-[:room]-(i3)
```

Following is my query

```
MATCH (place:`Place` {name: 'P'}),
      (place)-[:place]-(room:Room)
OPTIONAL MATCH (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]-(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (room)-[:room]-(date:UnavailableDate)
OPTIONAL MATCH (room)-[:room]-(image:Image)
WITH DISTINCT place,
     collect(room) AS r,
     collect(image) AS images,
     collect(date) AS dates,
     type(tenant) AS type,
     u
WITH place,
     collect({type: type, u: u}) AS tenants,
     collect({rooms: r, images: images, dates: dates}) AS rooms
RETURN DISTINCT place,
       rooms,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'owner_of'   | [tenant.u]][0] AS owner_array,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'house_mate' | [tenant.u]] AS house_mates_array
```

Result
[image]
Here I am trying to figure out to get

1. place should be distinct in result
2. every room should have its unavailable dates & images as separate Array in room result
3. owner & housemate array looks good should be as it is

*problem is collect for images & dates should be on room not on place*

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicates are coming from the back-to-back OPTIONAL MATCHes. You're getting cross products for all combinations of `u`, `date`, and `image`. To avoid this, you need to collect immediately after each one. 
Or, even better, use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to get the result into a collection right away, and use [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) in the final collection to add the dates and images into each associated room:

```
MATCH (place:`Place` {name: 'P'})
WITH place, [(place)-[:owner_of]-(u:User) | u] as owner_array, [(place)-[:house_mate]-(u:User) | u] as house_mates_array
MATCH (p)-[:place]-(room:Room)
WITH place, owner_array, house_mates_array, room, [(room)-[:room]-(date:UnavailableDate) | date] as dates, [(room)-[:room]-(image:Image) | image] as images
RETURN place, collect(room {.*, dates, images}) as rooms, owner_array, house_mates_array
```

Comment: Thanks for less & effective query, I learned a lot from it @IverseFalcon

Answer (score 1):

This may be close to what you want:

```
MATCH (place:`Place` {name: 'P'})-[:place]-(room:Room)
OPTIONAL MATCH (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]-(u:User)
WITH place, room, TYPE(tenant) AS type, u
OPTIONAL MATCH (room)-[:room]-(date:UnavailableDate)
OPTIONAL MATCH (room)-[:room]-(image:Image)
WITH place, room,
     collect(image) AS images,
     collect(date) AS dates,
     collect(DISTINCT {type: type, u: u}) AS tenants
RETURN place,
       collect({room: room, images: images, dates: dates}) AS room_data,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'owner_of'   | [tenant.u]][0] AS owner_array,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'house_mate' | [tenant.u]] AS house_mates_array;
```

Here are the results:

```
╒════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"place"     │"room_data"                                                           │"owner_array" │"house_mates_array"│
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│{"name":"P"}│[{"room":{"name":"r2"},"images":[{"url":"http://.."},{"url":"http://..│[{"number":2}]│[[{"number":1}]]   │
│            │"},{"url":"http://.."},{"url":"http://.."}],"dates":[]},{"room":{"name│              │                   │
│            │":"r1"},"images":[{"url":"http://.."},{"url":"http://.."},{"url":"http│              │                   │
│            │://.."},{"url":"http://.."}],"dates":[{"date":"1/1/2016"},{"date":"1/2│              │                   │
│            │/2016"},{"date":"1/1/2016"},{"date":"1/2/2016"}]}]                    │              │                   │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam your query is giving correct result as well :)